# Pandas でエクセルファイルを取り込んだデータフレームの name で AttributeError が発生する

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pycharm

以下の記事を参考に作業しています。

[Excelシートをデータフレームとして読み込む](https://datumstudio.jp/blog/1722/#Excel)

```
pd_xl = pd.ExcelFile(<略>)

temp_df = pd_xl.parse(sheet_name=<略>, names=<略>)
temp_df = temp_df.fillna('-')
print('temp_df.name-->', temp_df.name)
```

というのをやると

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

というエラーが出るのですが、parseのnamesで指定した内容を読みだすには、どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

［環境］
PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)
Python 3.8.5
Windows 10 Home(21H2 64bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.ExcelFile.parse](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)は[pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)と同じです。

parseの説明はこうなっています。

> Parse specified sheet(s) into a DataFrame.
> Equivalent to read_excel(ExcelFile, …) See the read_excel docstring for more info on accepted parameters.

read_excelのnamesパラメータの説明はこちら。

> names : array-like, default None
> List of column names to use. ...以後省略

つまり列の名前なので、列名のインデックスオブジェクトとしては`.columns`、列名のリストとしては`.columns.values` とか `.columns.tolist()` を `temp_df` に対して指定すれば良い訳です。
[pandas.DataFrame.columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)

> The column labels of the DataFrame.

[pandas.Index.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html?highlight=values#pandas.Index.values)

> Return an array representing the data in the Index.

[pandas.Index.tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html?highlight=tolist#pandas.Index.tolist)

> Return a list of the values.

参考：
[pandasの使い方 〜列名や行名を取得する〜](https://mryksy.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/18/130343)
[pandas.DataFrameの構造とその作成方法](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-dataframe-values-columns-index/)

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございました。ご回答いただいた内容で解決しました。